# Excel VBA Delete specified values in list on second go around

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a list of 100 rows of data, and there are 6 unique values in those 100 rows.  I am trying to run a for/next statement to randomly pull a value from that list and then delete every row of data in the list of 100 that match the value that I pulled.  Then, I would like to repeat this process on the new data set (for example, if there was a list of 100 items and it 14 of them said "Apple" and Apple was the returned value, I want it to delete all cells that say "Apple", and run the process on the remaining 86 cells).  The ultimate product is a randomly ranked list of all 6 unique values with no duplicates

Right now, I am able to run the process the right number of times and everything works except it will only delete cells on the first time through.  So, if i pull "Apple" the first time through it will delete all instances of "Apple", but if I pull "Orange" the second time through it will not delete all instances of "Orange" and as a result, I may pull "Orange" again, which would give me duplicates.

Really, I am just trying to figure out why the portion of code to delete the last unique value pulled from the remaining list of rows only works the first go around (the portion below (' delete rows in team list that match draft pick selection).  What I am trying to achieve is incorporate odds into a fantasy hockey draft lottery (so worst team has a 29% chance of first pick overall, they are listed 29 times out of 100 in the list).  Any tips that limit how much i have to rewrite would be great.  Everything i want it working, except once the first unique value is pulled from the list and I only have the remaining five other values, the portion of code that is supposed to remove the next pick from the list the second time around stops working. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code portion:

```
Dim TeamCount As Long, TeamPick As Range
Dim DraftPick As Range, TeamList As Range, NonPlayoffTeams As Range
Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer, counter1 As Integer

Set TeamPick = Range("f4")
Set NonPlayoffTeams = Range("b20:b25")
i = 1

For counter = 1 To NonPlayoffTeams.Rows.Count

    'count number of teams in list

    TeamCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Range("J2"), Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)))

    'pick a random number between 1 and count of teams listed and show that team name in that cell from the list

    TeamPick = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(Range("J2"), Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)),   Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, TeamCount))

    'set the teamlist as the range of all the teams copied and pasted earlier

    Set TeamList = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    ' delete rows in team list that match draft pick selection

    For counter1 = 1 To TeamList.Rows.Count
        If TeamList.Cells(i) = TeamPick Then
            TeamList.Cells(i).Delete
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    Set TeamPick = TeamPick.Offset(1, 0)

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This will copy all the values from column **A** to column **B**.  It removes all the duplicates in column **B**.  Then it randomizes column **B**:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim N As Long, InOut() As Variant
    Range("A:A").Copy Range("B1")
    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim InOut(1 To N)
    For I = 1 To N
        InOut(I) = Cells(I, "B").Value
    Next I
    Call Shuffle(InOut)
    For I = 1 To N
        Cells(I, "B").Value = InOut(I)
    Next I
End Sub

Public Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For I = Low To Hi
        Helper(I) = Rnd
    Next I


    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For I = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(I)
            Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
            Helper(I + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(I)
            Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
            Helper(I + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to remove duplicates.  I would like to select one from a list of 100, add that selection to a separate list, and then remove that unique value from the original list, and repeat.  For example, say I have a list of 10 items, and those ten items say either "apple", "banana", or "pear".  To start, it MUST say Apple 5 times, Banana 3 times, and Pear twice.  I randomly pick one item, say it is pear.  Then I want to to delete all instances of pear.  So I should be left with a list of 8 that says Apple 5 times and banana 3 times.  I want to repeat the process on the new list.

Answer (score 0):

> What I am trying to achieve is incorporate odds into a fantasy hockey draft lottery (so worst team has a 29% chance of first pick overall, they are listed 29 times out of 100 in the list).

FWIW, I recommend a simpler approach than listing the team 29 times and then removing all instances of the chosen team.  Instead, you lay-out the odds in a normalized cumulative probability array, pick a single random value between zero and one, then do a lookup into the array.  Update the probabilities and repeat.  You can even do this in a regular spreadsheet and may not have to use VBA at all.

Try something like this:

[image: Worked-out solution in Excel]